# How I can organize correct rbac hierarchy for some roles with rules in yii2?

Tags: yii2, rbac

I want make hierarchy RBAC different for some user roles.

Rbac system checked in reverse and recursive for roles and permissions (checkAccess function in DBManager). 
I don't understand how I can make chain roles/permission for concrete user Role.

I have postController. Roles: admin, author. Permission updatePost.

And two Permissions busyPostRule, authorPostAccessRule.

For example, for admin role I need chain in order (updatePost - busyPostRule - admin)
for author (updatePost - authorPostAccessRule - busyPostRule - author).
How I safe these order checks for user roles?

Admin only busyPostRule.

Author first authorPostAccessRule, second busyPostRule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bht8d.png)

In postController AFC:

```
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['update'],
                    'roles' => ['updatePost'],
                ],
```

If admin role opened update page:

chain (updatePost - busyAdminRole - admin),
but if author role:

chain (updatePost - busyAdminRole - admin - BACK - authorAccessRole - busyAuthorRole - author).

How ignore check "busyAdminRole" ?

Comment: I think you misunderstanding the way how the RBAC has to work. `admin` has to have all  privileges with let's say `delete` role and author can have `update` role, user just view the post. So `admin` can `delete, update` post but `author` can just `update`. Every role is inherited from the lower one. So the admin inherit author access privileges. You can learn more here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization

Answer (score 0):

Try mdmsoft/yii2-admin, you can setup your roles, permissions and routes as you need on the go.

https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin

Also has helpers like:

use mdm\admin\components\Helper;

````
'columns' => [
    ...
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => Helper::filterActionColumn('{view}{delete}{posting}'),
    ]
]```
````